# Instance Static variable not initialize in method if method is called above it

Tags: variables, static, instance, final

```
public class MainClass {
   static final int i = GetI();
   static int j = 9;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("i value : " + i);
   }

   static int GetI() {
      return j;
   }
}
```

Above code prints 'i value : 0' 
1. But, the method should return the value of j which is 9 and so the value of i will be 9.
2. If we make variable j as final, then the out put will be 'i value : 9', which is fine.

What might be the reason?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared **variable j after variable i is getting initialized**. In main method, you were acessing **i** which is calling the GetI() method. GetI() method is returning **j**, till that time j is not being initialized. You did not get error also for accessing j because it is declared as static variable it's scope is class lebel. Output is - 0 because default value of int is 0 which is being used if not initialized.
Try - declare variable **j** before **i** then output will be 9 which you want. Doing this, will initialize variable j before it is going to be used later.
Hope this help.